# Calculating the sine fourier series for wave equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, fourier-series, wave-equation

We have equation $y_{xx}=y_{tt}$  with conditions

$y(0,t)=y(2,t)=0$
and $y(x,0)=f(x)$ and $y_t(x,0)=g(x)=0$ for $0 < x < 2$

where 
$
f(x)=
\begin{cases}
 0.1x&\text{if}\, 0 \le x \le1\\
 0.1(2-x)&\text{if}\, 1 \le x \le 2\\
\end{cases}
$

I have the formula $$
f(x) =\sum_{n=1}^\infty A_n \sin(\frac{n\pi}{L})x$$  $$A_n=\frac{2}{L} \int_{0}^{L}f(x)\sin(\frac{n\pi x}{L}) dx$$ 
 $$g(x) =\sum_{n=1}^\infty B_n \sin(\frac{n\pi}{L})x
$$

$$B_n=\frac{2}{L} \int_{0}^{L}g(x)\sin(\frac{n\pi x}{L}) dx$$

Now the  sine series of $$f(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{0.8}{n^2\pi^2}sin(\frac{n\pi x}{2})sin(\frac{n\pi x}{2})$$

but I have no idea how to arrive at this. They didn't add the piecewise sections together otherwise a product wouldn't show up in the answer. What did they use for $f(x)$?

Answer (score 1):

You have
$$
f(x) = \sum_{n = 1}^\infty A_n \sin\left(\frac{\pi n}{2}x\right),
$$
where
$$
A_n = 0.1 \int_0^1 x \sin\left(\frac{\pi n}{2}x\right) dx + 0.1 \int_1^2 (2 - x) \sin\left(\frac{\pi n}{2}x\right) dx = 0.1 \frac{8}{\pi^2 n^2}\sin\left(\frac{\pi n}{2}\right),
$$
therefore
$$
f(x) = \sum_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{0.8}{\pi^2 n^2} \sin\left(\frac{\pi n}{2}\right)\sin\left(\frac{\pi n}{2}x\right).
$$

I think you/someone else just made a typo in the expression of $\sin\left(\frac{\pi n}{2}\right)$ adding $x$ in the argument.

Comment: Thanks! And suppose the function had jump discontinuity at 1,would the process be the same? So instead of 0.1(2-x) suppose it was 0.1(3-x).

Comment: I guess the formal expression remains the same, but you should be carefull.  Recommend you to read about https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gibbs_phenomenon